# Programatically setting auto layout constraints for a UIView's subviews

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

Below I have included some code for you to checkout. I am trying to take a custom `UIView` and add another custom subview to it. This subview should be constrained to the parent view in such a way it essentially just lays on top with the same dimensions and the parent just acts as a wrapper.

I have tried using the `NSLayoutConstraint` and failed miserable so far. The view never actually shows up. I have a left, right, bottom, and top constraint which should line up with the parent view.

The first ask I have is that someone please explain and or correct my logic when using the following method. The item param I figured is the actual view you want to set a constraint for (`customViewChild`). The attribute is to say that I want the left edge of my `customViewChild` to be used for this constraint. The `relatedBy` seems pretty straight forward although I could be wrong, and then finally the `toItem` points to self which is my `CustomViewParent` which also has a `.left` attribute to say that I want the left edge of my child and parent to line up. Is this logic flawed or am I doing something else wrong?

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: customViewChild!, 
            attribute: .left, 
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: self,
            attribute: .left, 
            multiplier: 1.0, 
            constant: 0.0)
```

I know the following example could very easily be done with IB, but I am trying to understand `NSLayoutConstraint`, so please provide answers regarding that. And lastly, if anyone could actually correct this code so I have a working example, that would be awesome.

```
class CustomViewParent: UIView {

    var customViewChild: UIView?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setConstraints()
    }

    func setConstraints() {
        customViewChild = UIView()

        addSubview(customViewChild!)
        customViewChild?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customViewChild!, 
            attribute: .left, 
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: self,
            attribute: .left, 
            multiplier: 1.0, 
            constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customViewChild!, 
            attribute: .right, 
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: self,
            attribute: .right, 
            multiplier: 1.0, 
            constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customViewChild!, 
            attribute: .top, 
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: self,
            attribute: .top,
            multiplier: 1.0, 
            constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customViewChild!, 
            attribute: .bottom, 
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: self,
            attribute: .bottom, 
            multiplier: 1.0, 
            constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        customViewChild.addConstraint([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Get rid of `customViewChild.addConstraint...`.  Setting the `isActive` to true adds them to the right views.

Comment: Are you creating the instance of `CustomViewParent` from a storyboard or nib file? If not then `init(coder:)` probably isn't being called. Use a breakpoint or log to confirm. Also, I suggest you us .leading and .trailing rather than .left and .right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things:

1. You don't need to use `addConstraint`.  Just set `isActive` to `true` for the constraints.
2. It doesn't make sense to both set `isActive` to `true` and to assign the result of that to a constant.  Setting the `isActive` property doesn't return the `NSLayoutConstraint`.  It returns `()`.
3. You should use `.leading` and `.trailing` instead of `.left` and `.right`.

With these changes, the following should work:

```
func setConstraints() {
    customViewChild = UIView()

    addSubview(customViewChild!)
    customViewChild?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: customViewChild!, 
        attribute: .leading, 
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: self,
        attribute: .leading, 
        multiplier: 1.0, 
        constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: customViewChild!, 
        attribute: .trailing, 
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: self,
        attribute: .trailing, 
        multiplier: 1.0, 
        constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: customViewChild!, 
        attribute: .top, 
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: self,
        attribute: .top,
        multiplier: 1.0, 
        constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: customViewChild!, 
        attribute: .bottom, 
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: self,
        attribute: .bottom, 
        multiplier: 1.0, 
        constant: 0.0).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You may find this a bit easier, and more readable...

```
func setConstraints() {

    if customViewChild == nil {
        customViewChild = UIView()

        addSubview(customViewChild!)
        customViewChild?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        customViewChild?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        customViewChild?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        customViewChild?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        customViewChild?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```